# What's the difference modifying a UIObject's base vs it's CALayer?

Tags: ios, swift

So I've been fiddling around with the UI elements and have found that a lot of things call for using the UIElement.layer to style the element over the UIElement itself even though they both have a lot of similar properties. What would be the difference between using

```
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor(color)
```

over

```
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.backgroundColor(color)
```

or any other property that can be set on the UI Element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them set the background color of the backed layer, set the `backgroundColor` property of `UIView` will call `CALayer`'s `setBackgroundColor:(CGColorRef)backgroundColor` method eventually.

Here's some hints, the call stack of UIView's `setBackgroundColor:`, you can see it call KDLayer's(KDLayer is subclass of CALayer) setBackgroundColor method.

[image]

Here is the code, it's Objective-C code but I think it's easy to understand.

`KDView` subclass `UIView`

```
@implementation KDView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [KDLayer class];
}

@end
```

`KDLayer` subclass `CALayer`

```
@implementation KDLayer

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(CGColorRef)backgroundColor {
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}

@end
```

Add a break point in KDLayer's setBackgroundColor: method and create a instance of KDView and modify it's `backgroundColor` property.

```
KDView *v = [KDView new];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

They're actually the same, except for the type (the view's backgroundColor is a UIColor, and the layer's is a CGColor)

```
var b:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
b.setTitle("Normal", for: UIControlState(rawValue: UInt(0)))
b.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
b.layer.backgroundColor == b.backgroundColor?.cgColor // returns "true"
```

The UIButton's backgroundColor property setters and getters just manipulate the view's layer properties. The documentation says that the UIView backgroundColor property was added in iOS 2.0, so before that, manipulating the layer was the only way to change it.